# Value of Ramanujan Summation In Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In mathematics, sum of all natural number is infinity.

but Ramanujan suggests whole new definition of summation.

"The sum of $n$ is $-1/12$" what so called [Ramanujan Summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation).

First he find the sum, only Hardy recognized the value of the summation.

And also in quantum mechanics(I know), Ramanujan summation is very important.

**Question.** What is the value of Ramanujan summation in quantum mechanics?

Comment: What's the value of the golden ratio in Newtonian mechanics? What's the value of 1+1/2+1/4+1/8+... in general relativity? You're mixing up math with unrelated physics.

Comment: http://vixra.org/abs/1003.0235 here my paper on how can the zeta regularization and Ramanujan resummation be used to get finite values in quantum mechanics

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lumo gives a very nice step by step calculation of this sum and a good discussion of the importance and application of such summation techniques in QFTs here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39811

Such mathematical calculations are NOT unrelated to physics; on the contrary they are important...